# Recognizing the interface that a packet comes from in pcap.net?

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, pcap.net

I'm building a bridge using a computer with two network interface controllers.
I'm using a multithread arrangement to receive packets form both interfaces using pcap.net. The problem is I don't know how to recognize what interface a packet is recived from. Do packets carry any information that can tell from what interface they got sniffed?

If not, a possible workaround would be to pass on a parameter to a callback function. Is that possible?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default event handler for `ReceivePackets` doesn't provide interface information. True! On the other hand, all it expects is a `delegate void` taking a single `Packet` parameter.

Let us provide one:

```
communicator.ReceivePackets(0, packet => PacketHandler(selectedDevice, packet));
```

We'll get the captured packet passed to our delegate, then call the packet handler passing in our device.

I've adapted an example found on the [Pcap.Net site](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Opening-an-adapter-and-capturing-the-packets).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using PcapDotNet.Core;
    using PcapDotNet.Packets;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<LivePacketDevice> allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            if (allDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i != allDevices.Count; ++i)
            {
                var device = allDevices[i];

                Console.Write((i + 1) + ". " + device.Name);

                if (device.Description != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" (" + device.Description + ")");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" (No description available)");
                }
            }

            int deviceIndex;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interface number (1-" + allDevices.Count + "):");
                var deviceIndexString = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(deviceIndexString, out deviceIndex) || deviceIndex < 1 || deviceIndex > allDevices.Count)
                {
                    deviceIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            while (deviceIndex == 0);

            var selectedDevice = allDevices[deviceIndex - 1];

            using (var communicator = selectedDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + selectedDevice.Description + "...");

                communicator.ReceivePackets(0, packet => PacketHandler(selectedDevice, packet));
            }
        }

        private static void PacketHandler(PacketDevice device, Packet packet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1} {2}", device.Name, packet.Timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), packet.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
1. rpcap://\Device\NPF_{0CDD10C5-9C40-47BD-811D-7CD24547CD28} (Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host)
2. rpcap://\Device\NPF_{3C97403E-012B-4912-96B1-F8E246F93BA0} (Network adapter 'Sun' on local host)
3. rpcap://\Device\NPF_{06217B0B-1804-4ADD-9BEE-4A7EBC63B009} (Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host)
4. rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09} (Network adapter 'Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection' on local host)
5. rpcap://\Device\NPF_{40199909-A7A1-4549-8D06-9DCE66F24A7E} (Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host)

Enter the interface number (1-5): 4

Listening on Network adapter 'Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection' on local host...
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.552 55
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.552 60
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.848 60
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.848 54
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.958 55
[rpcap://\Device\NPF_{C189488C-4DD5-4410-981B-A5929234AC09}] 01:59:49.958 55
```